# Enable auto-save based on filename

Tags: auto-save

How can I enable auto-save based on filename?  I use a naming convention (a prefix to the filename) for my notes and I'd like to enable auto-save for those files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there is a "correct" way to make this happen.

What comes to my mind is:

```
(defvar my-auto-save-regexp "/jdigit")

(defun my-auto-save-mode-fn ()
  (when (string-match my-auto-save-regexp buffer-file-name)
    (auto-save-mode 1)))

(add-hook 'find-file-hook 'my-auto-save-mode-fn)
```

Comment: it works, thank you.