# How to disable the generation of auto-save files (e.g. #file.org#, .#file.org# and file.org~)?

Tags: org-mode, auto-save, backup

I'm new to Emacs and `org-mode`. Whenever I make changes to any org file it creates auto-save files. For example if the file I'm editing is `tasks.org`, it creates these files : `#tasks.org#`, `.#tasks.org#` and `tasks.org~`.
I want to disable this behaviour.

PS: I'm using Emacs on Windows

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To not create backup files (`*~`), customize option `make-backup-files`.
2. To not create auto-save files (`#...#`), turn off `auto-save-mode` in your init file:

```lisp
(auto-save-mode -1)
```

But do so at your peril. Better to search this site for tag `[auto-save]`, to see other possibilities. Better yet: read the [Emacs manual about auto-save](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Auto-Save.html) files.

However, if you only want to disable auto-save for Org files, then this question should be deleted as a duplicate of [this one](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/54869). In that case, please delete your question.

Comment: Does this disable backups ending with `~` as well? Or `(setq make-backup-files nil)` needed?

Comment: The original question includes disabling saving files ending with `~`, which are backup files. You should add that to your answer.